# multiple headers and pagination in a book

Tags: header-footer, page-numbering, fancyhdr

For some reason I get "Table of Contents" on every odd page. The other problem being the pagination which is reset after the second edition in the main matter. Help much appreciated. Here's the code for `Brillpreamble`:

```
% XeLaTeX can use any Mac OS X font. See the setromanfont command below.
% Input to XeLaTeX is full Unicode, so Unicode characters can be typed directly into the source.

% The next lines tell TeXShop to typeset with xelatex, and to open and save the source with Unicode encoding.

%!TEX TS-program = xelatex
%!TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{ledmac}
\linenummargin{inner}
\sidenotemargin{outer}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancyhf{} % sets both header and footer to nothing
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
% your new footer definitions here
\fancyhead[CE,CO]{Text 1} 
\fancyhead[CE,CO]{Text 2}
\usepackage{adforn}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{hanging}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\textheight = 180.5 mm
\textwidth = 108.5 mm
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\usepackage[hang]{footmisc}
\setlength{\footnotemargin}{12pt}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@makefntext[1]{%
  \noindent\makebox[1em][r]{\@makefnmark}#1}
\makeatother
\usepackage{imakeidx} 
\makeindex[name=nominum, title=Index nominum, columns=2]
\makeindex[name=rerum, title=Index rerum, columns=2]
\pretolerance=100
\usepackage{microtype}

%\usepackage{geometry}                % See geometry.pdf to learn the layout options. There are lots.
%\geometry{a4paper}                   % ... or a4paper or a5paper or ... 
%\geometry{landscape}                % Activate for for rotated page geometry
%\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}    % Activate to begin paragraphs with an empty line rather than an indent
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{amssymb}
%\renewcommand %These two commands are for double-spacing
%\baselinestretch{2}

% Will Robertson's fontspec.sty can be used to simplify font choices.
% To experiment, open /Applications/Font Book to examine the fonts provided on Mac OS X,
% and change "Hoefler Text" to any of these choices.

\usepackage{fontspec,xltxtra,xunicode}
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
\setromanfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Brill}
\setsansfont[Scale=MatchLowercase,Mapping=tex-text]{Gill Sans}
\setmonofont[Scale=MatchLowercase]{Andale Mono}
\frenchspacing

\newfontfamily{\H}[Scale=0.9]{Lucida Grande}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{aboveskip=5pt}

\def\changemargin#1#2{\list{}{\rightmargin#2\leftmargin#1}\item[]}
\let\endchangemargin=\endlist

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0} % sections are level 1
```

And here's my main file:

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside]{book}
\input{Brillpreamble}
\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\include{titleBrill}
\renewcommand\contentsname{Table of Contents}
\tableofcontents
\include{abbrevBrill}
\include{prefaceandintroBrill}
\mainmatter
\include{RainoldetextBrill}
\include{MedlyetextBrill}
\backmatter
\printindex[nominum]
\printindex[rerum]
\include{BiblioBrill}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The question has been crossposted on [LaTeX-community.org](http://latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=47&t=26520&p=90826#p90801) a few days ago.

Answer (score 2):

The whole issue is that the wrong `pagestyle` was used. Explicit `\clearpage\pagestyle{fancy}` just before the `\tableofcontents` or even `\pagestyle{plain} helps to cure this problem.

*I've deleted all unnecessary code for this solution*

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside]{book}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancyhf{} % sets both header and footer to nothing
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
% your new footer definitions here
\fancyhead[CE,CO]{Text 1} 
\fancyhead[CE,CO]{Text 2}
\setlength{\headheight}{15pt}
\pagenumbering{arabic}


\usepackage{blindtext}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0} % sections are level 1

\renewcommand\contentsname{Table of Contents}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\blindtext[20]
\clearpage
\pagestyle{plain}
\tableofcontents
\cleardoublepage
\pagestyle{fancy}
\mainmatter

\chapter{Foo}
\blindtext[20]
\backmatter
\chapter{Bar}
\blindtext[20]
\end{document}
```